# Read through files in a folder

Tags: python, file

I have a folder with files of certain extension name, eg : 'LRZ_OA_12115.txt'. I have hundreds of files with these names. The following is the task:
i) I want to get access to each of these files in the numeric order. For examples, I will like to have LRZ_OA_12115 before LRZ_OA_12116. 
ii) I want to get access of and read this part : 12115 ( not the alphabets) of each files in the folder.

I will appreciate any answer.

Thanks.

Comment: sort using `lambda x : int(os.path.splitext(x)[0])` as key. But you have to check if filenames are all digits else you'll get an exception.

Comment: 12115 before 12116 is not numeric order, it's alphanum order. You need 2 before 10 right?

Comment: Yes. I have edited the question to include there are 'texts' as well in the file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [os](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#module-os) and [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html) functions from the Python standard library.

```
for filename in sorted(os.listdir('<your-directory>')):
    name, _ = os.path.splitext(filename)
    # do something with name
```

As Jean-François Fabre notes, this gives [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (12115 before 12116, but 2 before 10) instead of strictly numeric order. If you need the latter, then modify the code like this:

```
sort_key = lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]) if os.path.splitext(x)[0].isdigit() else 0
for filename in sorted(os.listdir('<your-directory>'), key=sort_key):
    ...
```

Comment: that's not going to sort numericaly.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
 import os, glob
 files = sorted(glob.glob(path + '*.txt'), key=os.path.basename)
```

For numerically you can do this:

```
 files = sorted(glob.glob('*.txt'), key=lambda name: int(os.path.splitext(name)[0]))
```

Comment: `>>> "12345678.txt"[4:-4]
'5678'`

Answer (score 1):

My proposal:

```
import os
the_dir = "/path/to/your/files"

print(sorted(os.listdir(the_dir),key = lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]) if os.path.splitext(x)[0].isdigit() else 0))
```

It sorts directory listing according to the numerical value of the name part (without extension), checking that this part is numerical to avoid exception when converting to integer (other names - if there are some - are left at the start, and not sorted)